# AB Testing that switch page using random session

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

I embeded a random code that will switching the home page between page A and page B with different layout.

As I do the code switching using session, the home page URL is always the same.

How can I do an AB Testing ? What is the best tool to use ?

I tries Optimisely , but i don't know how they works as they ask for changing the Variatn #1 using their editor

Answer (score 0):

You could track the variations with Google Analytics (Universal Analytics) using either custom dimensions, by sending an event to indicate which test version was used or by dynamically modifying the page name. This is to track the variation, if you need logic on when to show variation A and when B, then something more is required.

Personally I would use custom dimensions if you don't need basic reporting for the variation names or events if you require basic reporting capability. Basic reporting refers to standard reports in Google Analytics, without the need to build a custom report.

**1) Custom dimension:**

Use a custom dimension to record page variation. This has the advantage of being a property that can be tracked at session or page level and will expand data, so you can still use the same page name for e.g. goals.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

The downside is that the custom dimensions are not available on standard reports and can't be used as a part of funnels.

**2) Trigger event for each variation**

Sending a non-interaction event to indicate a variation has been shown has the advantage to be seen in standard reports and you can use it with other events to form a funnel as well. The downside is that other goal steps indeed need to be events. This is not a problem if you use segments and not goals.

Remember to set the nonInteraction property to keep your bounce rate realistic.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Example:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'test variation', 'testname', 'variationname', {'nonInteraction': 1});
```

**3) Modify page name**

If you are able to modify the page name sent to GA, this helps to identify which page version was shown. This is a very simple method to implement and goes well with page based goal tracking, but the downside is that you can't "join" the pages together in tracking.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overriding